# Перевод сайта на локальную машину

Tags: php

Перенес сайт на локальную машину, возникла след. проблема. 
Сайт написан на фреймворке, в папке Components есть x4framework  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Главная страница сайта работает, однако при переходе по любой ссылке, например http://localhost/news/n/45 - сервер возвращает 404.
Можете подсказать хотя бы в каком направлении копать?
Возможна какая то проблема в routes?
Содержание .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(([^/\?]*/?)*)$ /index.php?call=$1

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

В апаче AllowOverride None, не могу включить. Когда включаю апач выдает ошибку

```
Reloading apache2 configuration (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!



<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Модуль rewrite включен.

В файле /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf добавил строки ниже 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Перезапустил апач - все та же ошибка 404.

Comment: Проверить работоспособность htaccess?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(([^/\?]*/?)*)$ /index.php?call=$1

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Вот все что там нашел. В корне.

Comment: Ну покажи детали ошибки, команда написана в ошибке как ее посмотреть. После этого можно понять в чем причина.

Comment: See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe"

Comment: не был подключен модуль rewrite в самом апаче.

Comment: Нужно ли AllowOverride None переключать в On в самом файле apache2.conf?